# pybind11: RuntimeError for passing Numpy Array

Tags: c++, numpy, pybind11

I'm trying to get pybind11 to accept a 3D unsigned integer numpy array that can be u8, u16, u32, or u64. However, after compiling, I get a RuntimeError. I tried enabling detailed error messages, but no dice. Does anyone see my mistake here?

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

#define PYBIND11_DETAILED_ERROR_MESSAGES

#include <vector>

#include "crackle.hpp"
#include "cc3d.hpp"

namespace py = pybind11;
py::tuple connected_components(const py::array &labels) {
    
    return py::make_tuple(...);
}


PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "comments.";
    m.def(
        "connected_components", 
        &connected_components,
        "Perform 4-connected components in layers on a 3D array."
    );
}
```

At runtime:

```
results = example.connected_components(labels)
```

RuntimeError: Unable to convert call argument to Python object (#define PYBIND11_DETAILED_ERROR_MESSAGES or compile in debug mode for details)

Here's my setup.py:

```
import setuptools
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension(
        "example",
        ["src/example.cpp"],
        extra_compile_args=["-std=c++17"],
    ),
]

setuptools.setup(
  setup_requires=['pbr'],
  cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules=ext_modules,
  pbr=True
)
```

Comment: You should define `PYBIND11_DETAILED_ERROR_MESSAGES` **before** including the pybind11 headers. Otherwise it's meaningless

Comment: ty I hadn't included "pybind11/stl.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to also write:

```
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
```

Pybind11 couldn't convert a vector to a list without it.